# struct of template class in template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

just tell me why it is not possible to use struct of template class in another template class.
i personally think it is logical. have c++ such feature?
I'm using VS 2015. thanks :)

```
template<typename T> class MyList
{
public:
    struct Node
    {
        T       value;
        Node*   next;
    };
    //...
};

template<typename Type> class MyMap
{
public:
    struct ElementData
    {
        Type        types[32];
        unsigned    key;
    };

    MyList<ElementData>::Node* nodes;   //Syntax Error: Identifier 'Node'
};
```

while this works.

```
template <typename T> struct Node
{
    T       value;
    Node*   next;
};

template<typename T> class MyList
{
public:
    Node<T>* root;
    //...
};

template<typename Type> class MyMap
{
public:
    struct ElementData
    {
        Type        types[32];
        unsigned    key;
    };

    Node<ElementData>* nodes;   
};
```

Comment: Do you know typename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add [`typename`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename) (for dependent type name `MyList<ElementData>::Node`) here,

```
typename MyList<ElementData>::Node* nodes;
```

> Inside a declaration or a definition of a template, typename can be used to declare that a dependent name is a type.

See [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/3309790)

Comment: Can it be achieved by "decltype" now?

Comment: @dahohu527 I don't think so, `decltype` needs an expression to get type from.